# How do I achieve a Windows 10 Installation using System32

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-8, system32, windows-7-embedded, network-driver

Is it possible to install a Windows 10 OS in a Computer operating on a Windows 7 using system32, and how should one go about it?[text](https://www.howtogeek.com/346997/what-is-the-system32-directory-and-why-you-shouldnt-delete-it/)

Nothing so far.
I have a PC running on a Windows 7 despite it being connected to internet I can't fire up the old browser.